# Замена кода в регулярных выражениях

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$str=file_get_contents("$page");
preg_match_all("/&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;<b>Текст:<\/b>(.+?)<BR>&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;/", $str, $name);
echo "<strong>Текст:</strong>";
echo $name[1][0];
echo "<br>";
```

Проблема в том что на сайте ссылки имеют сокращенный вид, вроде index.php. Поэтому у меня на сайте ити же ссылки не работают. Как можно заменить href="ssilka.php"  на href="http://www.sait.ru/ssilka.php". Ну или каким то образом создать страницу ssilka.php у меня на сайте которая бы перенаправляла на тот сайт и сохраняла метод _GET в ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то как-то так

```
$pattern = '/href="([^"]*)"/i';
$replacement = '/href="URL/${1}"';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $YOUR_STRING);
```

Заменит в тексте все ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно заменить href="ssilka.php"
> на
> href="http://www.sait.ru/ssilka.php".

заменить можно так:

```
$pref = "http://www.sait.ru/";
$page = '... Как можно заменить href="ssilka.php" на href="ssilka2.php".';

$page = preg_replace('#href="([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)"#i', 'href="'.$pref.'$1"', $page);
echo $page;
```

Будет выведено: **... Как можно заменить href="*http://www.sait.ru/ssilka.php*" на href="*http://www.sait.ru/ssilka2.php*".**